# How to write csv file with awk containing commas

Tags: linux, csv, awk

I have the file like this

```
field1****This is, sample text ", here and there"@@@@field2****This is, sample text ", here and there"@@@@field3****This is, sample text ", here and there"@@@@
```

`**** is the field separator`

`@@@@ is the record separator`

i want the csv with like this

```
field1, "This is, sample text ", here and there""
```

so that i can open in microsoft excel and its displays in two columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat file
field1****This is, sample text ", here and there"@@@@field2****This is, sample text ", here and there"@@@@field3****This is, sample text ", here and there"@@@@

$ gawk -F'\\*\\*\\*\\*' -v OFS=', ' -v RS='@@@@\n?' '{$2="\"" $2 "\""}1' file
field1, "This is, sample text ", here and there""
field2, "This is, sample text ", here and there""
field3, "This is, sample text ", here and there""

$ gawk -F'\\*\\*\\*\\*' -v OFS=', ' -v RS='@@@@\n?' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i="\"" $i "\""}1' file
"field1", "This is, sample text ", here and there""
"field2", "This is, sample text ", here and there""
"field3", "This is, sample text ", here and there""
```

Comment: I have the large text files. if i open new file in excel then some of the lines from column2 are coming as column1 of next record.

Comment: I'm not surprised as the output format you asked for looks very odd. Update your question with the input and output that's causing you problems.